# Concat Multiple Columns into new column Spark R data frame with a Seperator

Tags: r, apache-spark, sparkr

Used two syntaxes none of them worked.

1)

```
df_final$concat <- paste(df_final$A,df_final$B,df_final$C,sep="/")
```

Error - no method for coercing this S4 class to a vector

2)

```
df_final$concat <- (df_final$A + "/" + df_final$B)
```

Error - This returned nulls.
Any help would be appreciated. All of the columns contain strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following syntax.

```
df_final$concat <- concat_ws(df_final$A,df_final$B,df_final$C,sep="/")
```